# Onde/ quando utilizar a função return() em R?

Tags: r

Tirei deste [excerto](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#implicit-versus-explicit-returns) as seguintes funções:

Função sem uso de `return`:

```
j01 <- function(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    0
  } else {
    10
  }
}
```

Função com uso de `return`:

```
j02 <- function(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(10)
  }
}
```

Ambas retornam o mesmo resultado.

Para `j01`:

```
j01(5)
#> [1] 0
j01(15)
#> [1] 10
```

Para `j02`:

```
j02(5)
#> [1] 0
j02(15)
#> [1] 10
```

Particularmente, nuca usei `return` nas estruturas condicionais e nunca tive problemas. Gostaria de saber onde/ quando usar a função `return` em `R`.

Eu até me lembrei da função `print`, a qual você precisa usar dentro de `for` para que os valores apareçam pra você no Console. Mas em `*apply`, `print` não é necessário. Talvez tenha algo em comum as duas funções (`return` e `print`) a depender de onde se utiliza em `R` (`for` tem como *environment* o `.GlobalEnv`, enquanto que `*apply` tem como *environment* a própria função).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No R, as funções irão retornar por padrão o último valor calculado, não importanto se `return()` foi usado ou não:

```r
f <- function(x) {
  x^3
  x^2
  sqrt(x)
}

f(9)
#> [1] 3
```

O uso do `return` pode te fazer alterar a ordem em que o resultado da função é retornado, caso seja necessário por algum motivo:

```r
g <- function(x) {
  x^3
  return(x^2)
  sqrt(x)
}

g(9)
#> [1] 81
```

Em particular, no livro Wickham, H. (2015) Advanced R Programming (que é do mesmo autor do link fornecido), temos o seguinte parágrafo, na Seção 6.6, página 94:

> Generally, I think it’s good style to reserve the use of an explicit `return()` for when you are returning early, such as for an error, or a simple case of the function. This style of programming can also reduce the level of indentation, and generally make functions easier to understand because you can reason about them locally.

Em um tradução livre,

> Geralmente, acho que é um bom estilo reservar o uso de um `return()` explícito para quando você retornar [o valor de uma função] mais cedo, como para um erro ou um caso simples da função. Este estilo de programação também pode reduzir o nível de indentação e geralmente torna as funções mais fáceis de entender porque você pode raciocinar sobre elas localmente.

Ou seja, ao menos para uma das maiores referência em programação em R, usar a função `return()` acaba sendo uma questão mais de estilo de programação do que de obrigatoriedade em si de utilizar este recurso. Eu, particularmente, sempre uso, mesmo quando não é necessário. A meu ver, isso deixa o meu código mais organizado.

Por fim, podemos avaliar se o uso de `return()` traz alguma mudança de desempenho no tempo de execução de `j01` e `j02`, ou seja, se há alguma diferença grande no desempenho da função com ou sem `return()`.

```r
j01 <- function(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    0
  } else {
    10
  }
}

j02 <- function(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    return(0)
  } else {
    return(10)
  }
}


library(microbenchmark)
library(ggplot2)

res <- microbenchmark(j01, j02, times = 100000)
res
#> Unit: nanoseconds
#>  expr min lq     mean median uq   max neval cld
#>   j01  25 26 28.55451     27 30 11199 1e+05   a
#>   j02  25 26 28.85948     27 30 23723 1e+05   a

autoplot(res)
```

[image]

Como podemos ver, tanto numérica quanto graficamente, a diferença no tempo de execução é mínima (o código com `return()` é 0.30497 *nanossegundos* mais lento em meu computador). Portanto, não faz diferença em termos de desempenho computacional usar ou não `return()` em função simples como estas.

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a [resposta de @marcus-nunes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/534536/117168).

Em R, toda expressão retorna um valor. Como `return` atua como escape e o padrão da `function` é sempre retornar a última expressão avaliada, `return` nunca é necessária.

Mas vejo dois casos em que pode ser útil, ambos para tornar o código mais legível.

O primeiro, já apontado por Marcus Nunes, é deixar explícitos onde estão todos os pontos de saída. Especialmente útil em código longo e quando partilha código com programadores de outras linguagens. Uma alternativa é armazenar em um objeto e expressá-lo no final:

```
j03 <- function(x) {
  if (x < 10) {
    resultado <- 0
  } else {
    resultado <- 10
  }
  resultado
}
```

O segundo é tornar o código mais compacto quando existem vários pontos de verificação e saída em uma sequência de operações. Por exemplo:

```
j04a <- function(x) {
  a <- x + 1
  if (a < 10) {
    0
  } else {
    b <- a*2
    if (b < 12) {
      10
    } else {
      c <- b/4
      if (c < 2) {
        1
      } else {
        d <- c/2
        exp(d)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Pode ser escrito como:

```
j04b <- function(x) {
  a <- x + 1
  if (a < 10) return(0)
  b <- a*2
  if (b < 12) return(10)
  c <- b/4
  if (c < 2) return(1)
  d <- c/2
  exp(d)
}
```