# Erro no R: nenhuma função da qual retornar, pulando para o nível superior

Tags: r

Eu rodei o seguinte código com sucesso:

```
valor <- 100000

if (valor >= 1000000) {
  "número grande"
} else {
  "número pequeno"
}
```

Mas quando tento rodar o código no formato abaixo:

```
valor <- 100000

if (valor >= 1000000) {
  return("número grande")
} else {
  return("número pequeno")
}
```

Ocorro o erro:
*Erro: nenhuma função da qual retornar, pulando para o nível superior*

Por que isso acontece?

Comment: A função `return()` deve ser utilizada dentro do escopo local de funções e nunca no escopo global. Relacionada(talvez duplicada) [Onde/ quando utilizar a função return() em R?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/534524/137387).

Answer (score -3):

`return` não retorna um valor no sentido de avaliar uma expressão e exibir o valor resultante. Ela encerra uma chamada e retorna o valor da expressão indicada para o local de origem da chamada. Por isso o uso típico com `function`. Por exemplo:

```
f2 <- function(x) return(x + x)

f1 <- function(x) return(f2(x))
```

Rodar `f1` gera uma pilha no ambiente global (um ambiente para `f1` dentro do global, um para `f2` dentro do de `f1`). `x + x` é avaliada dentro do ambiente de `f2`; o `return` em `f2` retorna o valor da avaliação para o ambiente de `f1` (onde a chamada para `f2` foi gerada), e o `return` em `f1` retorna o valor para o ambiente global:

```
f1(2)
#> [1] 4
```

Se usar `return` no ambiente global, ela não encontra para onde direcionar o valor, gerando o erro:

```
2 + 2
#> [1] 4

return(2 + 2)
#> Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

Para uma explicação mais detalhada (e mais precisa), veja a [sessão 3.5 do Manual de Definições da Linguagem R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables) (em inglês).

---

*OBS 1*: R não possui uma função para avaliar uma expressão e gerar um valor no mesmo ambiente porque [isso é o que o interpretador sempre faz](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Evaluation-of-expressions).

*OBS 2*: Embora `return` faça parte da estrutura de `function`, ela pode ser usada em outros casos onde diferentes ambientes são criados ou indicados, como com `eval`:

```
eval(expression({
  2 + 2
}))
#> [1] 4

eval(expression({
  if (TRUE) return(10)
  2 + 2
}))
#> [1] 10
```

*OBS 3*: O uso de `return` em funções não é necessário. Veja [esta postagem sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/534524/137387) (indicada por @augusto-vasques nos comentários).